# Determining if Point is in Polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, intersection, geofencing

I want to check if a point is inside a fenced polygon.

```
INSERT INTO polygon (name, geom) VALUES ('test', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[0,0], [0,5], [5, 5], [5,0]]}'));

SELECT * FROM polygon WHERE name = 'test' AND ST_Intersects(geom, 'POINT(2 2)');
SELECT * FROM polygon WHERE name = 'test' AND ST_Contains(geom, 'POINT(2 2)');
```

Ideally, I'd expect it to return the row inserted as it should lie within the area. But I get 0 rows for both queries.

I also tried with much bigger, and more realistic data (using lat/long from a map), but I simply cannot get it working and the docs don't seem to help either?

Answer (score 4):

The polygon is not defined properly, making it an empty geometry. You need to add an extra square bracket. The [doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6) says that polygons are defined by an array of linear rings, to allow having holes.

While at it, let's make a valid polygon by having the same first and last coordinate.

```
select st_astext(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[0,0], [0,5], [5, 5], [5,0]]}'));
    st_astext
-----------------
 POLYGON Z EMPTY
(1 row)


select st_astext(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0,0], [0,5], [5, 5], [5,0], [0,0]]]}'));
         st_astext
----------------------------
 POLYGON((0 0,0 5,5 5,5 0,0 0))
(1 row)
```

Comment: Was just typing this up myself. I can't imagine why `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` should return `POLYGON Z EMPTY` on this input, so I [reported](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4164#ticket) it as a bug.

Comment: @dbaston What do you believe is wrong, the Z part or the Empty part (or both?)

Comment: Both. I'd expect a parse error.

Comment: Invalid, non-closing WKT `select ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 5,5 5,5 0))')`yields `ERROR: geometry contains non-closed rings`. But `select st_astext(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0,0], [0,5], [5, 5], [5,0]]]}'));` gives an invalid, non-closing polygon as a result: "POLYGON((0 0,0 5,5 5,5 0))".

Comment: Yes, and my point is that obviously GeomFromJSON is not validated as strictly as GeomFromText. Perhaps @dbaston could mention also that in the bug report.